# What plugins create a directory on the root directory of WordPress?

Tags: directory

How can I detect if a plugin or a program is creating a folder on the root directory of my WordPress site? How will I know if I could safely remove them?

Comment: WP doesn't create backups by default. So either some plugin or some person must have created these. You need to ask either of them what they are for, I'm sorry but we cannot help you for this.

Comment: There are no other backup plugins other than Updraft and it looks like it's being updated continuously because the new files are from today.

Comment: Someone or something must be creating these backups. That's all I can tell you. I would go to my hoster asking about this. They should be able to tell you if they're always created at the same time, if they are created on the server or simply uploaded, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do here is first rename the folder to something else, this way if something breaks you can just rename it back.
After a couple if days if all is well on the site just delete it.
Backup folders and files usually cause more issues  than they are worth. If you haven't needed a backup from 2018 chances are you never will.